# How can I make a table showing $x$ and $3\,x^2$ for a sequence of values of $x$

Tags: output-formatting, list-manipulation

How can I evaluate $3\,x^2$ for $x = 0,1,2, \ldots,10$ and display the answer as a two-column table, the 1st column being the values of $x$ and the 2nd column being the value of $3\,x^2$.

Comment: `Table[{x, 3x^2}, {x,0,10}] //Grid`?. Please read [asking guidelines](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and next time provide code to work with. Put some effort in wording too, there is no equation to solve there, especially if you insert `x` values.

Comment: Thank you @Kuba .I just search in mathematica.Thank you for the reminder. Will remember that before I post in future.

Comment: So does `Table` solve your problem?

Comment: Or `{#, 3 #^2} & /@ Range[0, 10] // Grid`

Answer (score 1):

As kuba mentioned in his comment

```
 Table[{x, 3 x^2}, {x, 0, 10}] // Grid
```

will do the job nicely, but I recommend you look at [`TableForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TableForm.html) as a replacement for `Grid` because it has some nice formatting options built into it.

```
TableForm[Table[{x, 3 x^2}, {x, 0, 10}],
  TableAlignments -> Right, TableHeadings -> {None, {"x"", "3 x^2"}}]
```

[image: table]